# How to check where my data is submit to in a HTML form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Currently I have a website with a input form, the problem is , how can I find where the form post data to?

There should be some php for the form to handle no matter using JSON / direct post.

Is it possible to get it in chrome developer / firebug or some tool ? Thanks

The source code of the form

```
<form action="/test-form/#wpcf7-f610-p611-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form sent" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="610">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.7.2">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f610-p611-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="4ddf1f1d07">
</div>
<p>姓<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-lastname"><input type="text" name="your-lastname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>名<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-firstname"><input type="text" name="your-firstname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>電子郵件<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>問題<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-question"><input type="text" name="your-question" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>內容<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-details"><textarea name="your-details" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="傳送" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://oshc.zizsoft.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;"><input type="button" value="清除"></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" role="alert" style="display: block;">Your message was sent successfully. Thanks.</div></form>
```

Comment: Sorry , is the question have some problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you already know that the "action" attribute sets this.
Use this to see all actual HTTP requests. http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

The `action` part of the form tells you where it is attempting to post the form data to.

In your case `action="/test-form/#wpcf7-f610-p611-o1"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted all the data to this page

```
/test-form/#wpcf7-f610-p611-o1
```

see your form's action attribute to see. The action value is the page where your form will be processed all data will be passed/posted to that page.

Unless you are using a javascript to alter the form's action.